# How can I display a list of local guides in my Sketchware Android app based on user location?

Tags: java, android, sketchware

I am developing an Android app using Sketchware and I want to add a feature where tourists can access the app and see guides available in their local area. I would like to display a list of guides based on the user's current location.

I have already implemented the user's location retrieval using the relevant APIs in Sketchware, but I'm unsure how to proceed with displaying the nearby guides and filtering them based on language skills and availability.

I did nothing yet but the app's UI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.